# Converting char[] to regular expression without String class

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write my very own `replaceAll()` method in java without using the `String` methods. I was wondering if there is a way to convert `cha[]` into regular expression? I noticed that the default `replaceALl()` takes in the regular expression as a `String`

Comment: In the default `replaceAll` method it is regex so I guess ideally regex would be in the `char[]`

Comment: Well, a `String` is "nothing more" than a wrapped `char[]`

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "a regular expression"?

Comment: @immibis regex for example. `[^\s]+` or `.*`

Comment: @Liondancer yes, but `"[^\\s]+"` and `".*"` are Strings. Alternatively, `new char[] {'[','^','\\','s',']','+'}` and `new char[] {'.','*'}` are char arrays. Alternatively, `new OneOrMoreMatcher(new InvertedCharacterSetMatcher(new WhitespaceCharacterSet()))` and `new ZeroOrMoreMatcher(new AnyCharacterMatcher())` are some kind of regular expression objects that don't exist in standard Java but that you could make yourself. And all of the above are regular expressions.